# Does here exists an analytic function $f:\mathbb C → \mathbb C$ such that $f(0) = 1, f(4i) = i$...

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Check whether the statement true or false?
There exists an analytic function $f:\mathbb C → \mathbb C$ such that $f(0) = 1, f(4i) = i$ and for all $z_j$ such that $1 < |z_j | < 3, j = 1, 2$, we have $$|f(z_1) − f(z_2)| ≤ |z_1 − z_2| ^{π /3}.$$

My attempt:-
$\because \pi/3>1.$ We can write $$\frac{|f(z_1) − f(z_2)|}{|z_1 − z_2|} ≤ |z_1 − z_2| ^{π /3-1}.$$ By the definition of derivative. $f'(z)=0,1 < |z | < 3$. By Identity Theorem $f'(z)=0$. Hence, $f(z)=Constant$. Which contradict to the proposition $f(0) = 1, f(4i) = i$. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Is there any particular reason why you were doubtful or is it just "I'm new to this, so I'd better check whether I didn't miss anything"?

Comment: Wait...I'm confused (but it may just be a lack of caffeine). Why isn't $f(z) = z$ a contradiction to the conclusion that $f'(z) = 0$? (I readily admit that $f(4i) \ne i$, but that never entered into the proof...)

Comment: @John Hughes Every Hölder continuous function with exponent $>1$ is constant. Here we have $\pi/3>1$. In particular, $f(x)=x$ does not satisfy $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le |x-y|^{\pi/3}$$

Comment: So that inequality states that (replacing $f(t)$ by $t$ everywhere) $|x - y| \le |x - y|^{1.04\ldots}$. ...ah...right. Now I see that for **small** values of $|x-y|$, this is false. D'oh. I really *did* need more caffeine.